# Converting the string "20111027" to a DateTime with a timezone of GMT

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string in this format: "20111027", i.e. of the general format: "yyyyMMdd".

How do I convert this to a DateTime having the **timezone GMT**?

This code does some conversion, but it's unclear what timezone would be used:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `DateTimeStyles` of `AssumeUniversal`:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                    DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

From the [docs of `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89.aspx):

> If no time zone is specified in the parsed string, the string is assumed to denote a UTC.

Sounds like exactly what you want :)

(Alternatively you could use [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) and parse it to a `LocalDate`. It only represents a date, after all, so why use a type which cares about times and time zones? :)

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

> If s does not represent a time in a particular time zone and the parse operation succeeds, the Kind property of the returned DateTime value is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.

You can change the `Kind` using [`DateTime.SpecifyKind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.specifykind.aspx):

```
date = DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```